# GCP-loadbalancer routing rule with regular expression

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, load-balancing, url-routing, rules

actually I am struggling with the routing rules definition for the gcp load-balancer. For my use-case I would need a regular expression so I used a snipped from the examples and tried to adapt it to my needs:

```yaml
defaultService: projects/***/global/backendServices/***
name: path-matcher-1
routeRules:
- matchRules:
    - prefixMatch: /mobile/
      headerMatches:
        - headerName: User-Agent
          regexMatch: .*Android.*  
  priority: 2
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
      - backendService: projects/***/global/backendServices/***
        weight: 100
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: android

- matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /
  priority: 1
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
    - backendService: projects/***/global/backendServices/***
      weight: 100
```

But I can do what I want, I always get following error:

[image]

Is there anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thx

Comment: Your expression is correct, the regex is simply not supported.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere are you really sure?! I copied that code from the examples in the documentation: "Traffic steering based on user agent with URL rewrite". 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps

*pathMatchers[].routeRules[].matchRules[].headerMatches[].regexMatch*

➡ regexMatch only applies to load balancers that have loadBalancingScheme set to **INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED**

and that is not my case